# Can a holding pattern be in class G airspace?

Tags: air-traffic-control, instrument-flight-rules, airspace, holding, class-g-airspace

Is separation provided between aircraft holding in class G airspace?
Could there be a holding stack in class G?

Comment: Which country or regulations are you asking about?

Comment: Pilots are told to hold in a holding pattern by ATC. Since they are under the control of ATC, by definition they are in controlled airspace. Class G is not controlled airspace so they couldn’t be required to hold in it.

Answer (score 4):

By definition, Class G is uncontrolled airspace so the only separation you will receive there comes from using your Mk I eyeballs and good judgment.  A controller is not going to dispatch you to hold in uncontrolled airspace.